Hexo next theme can't render search box correctly
I was using hexo to build my own blog: blog url
I want to add a search box to my blog.
So I add
search:
  path: search.xml
  field: post
  content: true
  format: html
  limit: 10000

to the _config.yml under the root directory of my blog folder (which is not in the theme folder)
and I changed the _config.yml in the theme folder to
local_search:
  enable: true
  # If auto, trigger search by changing input.
  # If manual, trigger search by pressing enter key or search button.
  trigger: auto
  # Show top n results per article, show all results by setting to -1
  top_n_per_article: 1
  # Unescape html strings to the readable one.
  unescape: false
  # Preload the search data when the page loads.
  preload: false

I also have typed npm install hexo-generator-searchdb --save in the git
To sum up, I have tried many ways on the web to add a search box. Above are my tries. However, the rendering still got some problem. By the way, it is OK when the website is local. When I visit localhost:4000/, the rendering is OK. But the deployed website has some rendering error with the search box.
The question is I didn't click the search button but the search box pop out automatically, yet in a wrong shape and display error. Because I am new to stackoverflow so I can't post pictures. I have provided my blog url blog-url.
I have searched the web and some article said that I should check my search.xml files. But I didn't find a search.xml in my web using F12. So I tried to find how to deal it when I don't have a search.xml, but I didn't get any useful answers.
I expect that the search box wouldn't pop out automatically until I click it and it should be rendered correctly.
